# Why are start and end segment not partially skipped?

Tags: pgrouting

Im using TRSP routing algo. I want to skip partially start and end segment part for point to point routing. Percent along start edge 0.6, percent along end edge 0.4. Route generated but start and end segment is not partially skipped.

Please help me. My query is as below.

```
select * from turn_restrict_shortest_path(
    'select gid as id, source::integer, target::integer,cost_fastest as cost, reverse_cost 
    from centre_line',
    17271,     -- edge_id for start
    0.6,   -- midpoint of edge
    14345,     -- edge_id of route end
    0.4,   -- midpoint of edge
    false,  -- directed graph?
    true,  -- has_reverse_cost?
    null)  -- no turn restrictions
```

Comment: Can you post query results both with and without skipping in the beginning? (The first few lines should be enough.)